# Recommended serverside architecture(framework/stack) to use with GWT for large application

Tags: gwt, architecture, server-side

I've been doing research on this for the past 2, almost 3 days now. I feel like I've googled everything under the sun on the matter (including these forums) and am almost all tutorialed-out. Before I go into any more details on the question I just want to give a quick overview of the scope and plan for the project to see what will suit it best:

-Large application, non-trivial
-50+ DB tables
-Large user base
-User management/authentication/sessions
-transactions
-security
-MVP (as per GWT recommendation)
-focus on performance and scalability (naturally :), am using GWT after all)
-Prefer to stick with Java serverside

I've also read and watched all of the best practices on architecture for large applications (Google/GWT). In the last talk I could find on best architecture practices involving GWT was back in 2010 by Ray Ryan in which he states that they don't think JavaBeans and property change events work terribly well so it's better to use DTOs for the Model.

The 2 frameworks that came to the forefront in my searching were Seam and Spring.

Sticking with MVP, my domain would for the most part be a data service with a thick client. However, I would still like the serverside to have security and session capabilities since I'd like users to be able to keep state even if they don't use cookies and they end up refreshing for example. I would also like to have an ORM like Hibernate to manage a lot of the transactional aspects. I'd like to still use RequestFactory and have really been considering Spring.

I guess I can narrow my question down to:

**Considering the above, what would the recommended application stack be for a large GWT application, specifically for the serverside and integration with GWT?**

This is my first project of this scale and the last thing I want to do is head down the wrong path on losing a lot of time and energy. Thanks a lot in advance for your help, I really just want to figure this out so I can get back to coding instead of googling the ends of the earth ;).

-Seth

I've also already looked at [Best architecture for applications in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957057/best-architecture-for-applications-in-gwt) which I found might be the closest to this, but it didn't really answer my question and I feel mine is a little more targeted with a more specific use case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have any experience with `Seam`, however I am working on a relatively large project using `GWT` on the frontend and `Spring` on the backend and so far it works really well (RequestFactory, JPA2/Hibernate, PostgreSQL). BTW you can also checkout [JBoss Erai](http://www.jboss.org/errai)

The good thing about using `Spring` is, that adding new features is quite easy. For example I added support for **openid authentication** and all I had to do is define an additional dependency in maven and some additional lines in the configuration file and now authentication via google,facebook, twitter account works out of the box.
This layered approach has a lot of advantages.

But if you really stick to the best practices of developing GWT apps (MVP, etc), you will end up with two more or less separate projects. This is a little bit different then when you would develop traditional Spring MVC/Web Flow apps where you have more or a less only one projects (btw: check out Thomas Broyer's [gwt maven archetypes](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes) which helps you come up with a good project structure).

In addtional to this when you use MVP on the client side your backend will actually only serve as a data service which feeds your GWT client with data. All the [flow synchronization](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/FlowSynchronization.html) will be handled in your GWT app.
So you will probably not use many of the backends functionality (i.e. the MVC part of `Spring MVC`).
I use `RequestFactory` for data communication between backend and frontend and for `CRUD` applications this works really well (it also supported from Android btw).
However if you want to support a more clients you might rather use a `Restless` approach. Again by using `Spring` on the backend it is relatively easy to add `Restless` support to your app and there are a couple of 3rd partys libraries supporting restful services in GWT ([RestyGWT](http://restygwt.fusesource.org/), [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/)).

Here are some thoughts on the development process:

- Use a **dependency management** system like `maven`. It makes it really easy to develop in teams and split up your projects in manageable units/modules (for example a GWT maven app can be split up in a frontend part (GWT), backend (Spring) part and a shared (comong DTO's, etc) part.
- Try to do **test driven development** (TDD or BDD). For example before you create a service function in your Spring backend (i.e. getAllProducts()) write a Unit test for it. This also helps creating a good Service layer because by writing Unit tests you define what the service layer is supposed to do.
- "[Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)": Don't put too much time in early optimizations.
- Think about buying/using [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/), especially if you use `Spring`. A relatively large `Spring` app can have a relatively large startup time. JRebel helps you to change classes in the backend without a reloading/restarting the application. It saves a lot of time.
- Implementing **ACL** on domain level is not an easy job. There are **ACL** classes in `Spring Security` and they work fine for simple use cases however if you have complex use cases (for example filter a list of items based on ACL entries) this can be quite involved if you want to do it efficiently. On the other hand with `Spring` it is relatively easy to use another library (i.e. Apache Shiro). Futhermore you have to make sure that you display the correct controls on the frontend (i.e. no Edit button if the user doesn't have edit permission, etc). With JSP that is easy because you create the UI (HTML page) on the backend. In `GWT` you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Hi Ümit, first and foremost I just want to say Wow and thank you. I also am really leaning to Spring with Hibernate, and already have postgresql. I just wasn't sure if I was being bought by marketing instead of actual worth/utility. My biggest source of doubt was if I needed something like Spring to achieve what I wanted above as I basically want to use the serverside as a data service as I didn't plan on using Webflow or Spring MVC. I made some edits to the my question above to try to open it back up and make it less vague - Do you still recommend that app stack for what I specified above?

Comment: Also, Errai looks pretty interesting, I never came across it while I searched, but will be looking into it more. And thanks for your development process thoughts, I'll definitely be getting more familiar with Maven and strongly keeping those points in mind, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I strongly believe that sticking to best practices and using standard frameworks/layers is the  way to go, especially if you work on a huge project. And that's the real strength of Java. In the core Spring is all about Inversion of Control (IoC) and alone for that I would recommend it. It also provides a lot of additional libraries (Security, MVC,etc) which you can use or not. By using the IoC pattern it is really easy to replace a specific implementation/class with a custom one. This way you use mostly well tested standard code but specific parts can be customized based on your use case.

Comment: I agree, the more modulated, the better. Thanks again for the great insight and the great answer Ümit. I really have a lot here that I'll be taking forward with me.